# Retrieve data from a database

Tags: liferay, liferay-6

I am working on liferay 6.2 . My Requirement is i need to Retrive data through database in liferay through service builder. can anyone help me out ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I recomend read: 
http://www.liferay.com/es/documentation/liferay-portal/6.2/development/-/ai/generating-your-service-layer-liferay-portal-6-2-dev-guide-04-en
In this page tell you everything you need
Besides install Liferay IDE  with eclipse, you can look:
http://www.liferay.com/es/documentation/liferay-portal/6.2/development/-/ai/developing-apps-with-liferay-ide-liferay-portal-6-2-dev-guide-02-en

Answer (score 0):

Get portlet from folloing location and try it.

https://github.com/liferay/liferay-plugins/tree/6.2.x/portlets/sample-service-builder-portlet

Need to run  following ant commands once you placed plugin in your plugins directory.

ant build-service

ant deploy